# How to get File Path from another project in one solution in ASP.NET MVC 3?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

Sorry if this question seems relevant to other questions that had been posted recently but i did not find any solution to my problem.

I have 2 projects in a solution. Project A and Project B. I am working on Project B, now i want to get the file path of a folder inside Project A name "DocumentUpload". My code only return path from the current project im working on.

Any answer is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

I am new to ASP.NET technology.

Comment: Why are you looking for it? Update the question with details.

Comment: I want to read a file inside "DocumentUpload" folder. PDF file to be specific. so i need to get the file path.

Answer (score 0):

After deployment there will be nothing like Project A and Project B. You need to consider where the files would be on the server. Based on that you need to provide the path.